# How to replace an image on the page with another image by clicking on the image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, filereader

I am not javascript or html expert. I know very basic.

Here is my code which I click on image open file chooser and I choose new image and this append it to previous image. This works fine but I need to replace the image with previous one instead of appending. Appreciate if any one can tweak it as I'm not sure how to do it:

```
<div id="current-user"></div>
<br>
<input type="file" id="choose" multiple src="/logo.png" />

<script>
function readImage(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = function(_file) {
        image.src    = _file.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = function() {
            var w = this.width,
                h = this.height,
                t = file.type,                           // ext only: // file.type.split('/')[1],
                n = file.name,
                s = ~~(file.size/1024) +'KB';
            $('#uploadPreview').append('<img src="'+ this.src +'"> '+w+'x'+h+' '+s+' '+t+' '+n+'<br>');
        };
        image.onerror= function() {
            alert('Invalid file type: '+ file.type);
        };      
    };

}
$("#choose").change(function (e) {
    if(this.disabled) return alert('File upload not supported!');
    var F = this.files;
    if(F && F[0]) for(var i=0; i<F.length; i++) readImage( F[i] );
});
</script>
```

**Edit:**

I could handle my page to bring an image and append it to previous image. But I need to remove the previous image and add a new image. I used to method of replaceWith() and replcaAll() but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$('#uploadPreview').append(...
```

Use:

```
$('#uploadPreview').html(...
```

Using `html()` method replaces all inner HMTL content from `#uploadPreview` element

Answer (score 1):

You may change the `src` attribute of your `img` element, that's easy way in my opinion:

```
    var img = document.getElementById("idOfImage");
    img.attributes.src.value = "2.jpg";           //URL of other image
```

And in this way you can also change the values of other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't empty the parent:

`$('#uploadPreview').empty();  //don't use this`

Just do:

`$('#uploadPreview').find("img").attr("src",this.src); //then you don't need to set height and width again`

Or follow this snippet:

```js
$("#image").on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr("src", "http://sd.keepcalm-o-matic.co.uk/i/keep-calm-its-already-done.png")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/W3FNHHH.png" height=200 width=200>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am actually adding following line before appending image:

`$('#uploadPreview').empty();`